# Architecture tips for multi-platform software / API

Tags: json, api, architecture, restful-architecture

I'm creating a multi-platform app, mostly for web interface, mobile and a windows application. The app will manage user task lists and sync them to the server, but also store them locally for processing data faster.

My idea of architecture until now is:

- Keeping most of the processing on client side, eventually syncing with the server.
- Developing an API to provide and receive data that will be saved on the server (basically just a json wrapper web service)

The data flow:
user Authenticates -> Requests updated Json objects to the server -> populate client-side objects -> work with client-side objects -> send a json object back to the server -> server updates data.

Is this a good approach? I've never done this, can you guys give me some tips?

Comment: I forgot to mention, I'm using Laravel + Mysql for backend and Jquery on frontend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are on the right track. The idea is to decouple the front-end from the back-end. The backend shall expose a set of CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) functions  as RESTful JSON web services. All your different flavours of UI (mobile, web, windows) can consume the same API.

I would recommend for the web front-end to take a look at AngularJS together with bootstrap.

Regarding the backend, you could implement it as a  simple Java web application with Jersey/JAX-RS or alternatively, you could check Node.js + Express.